# Azure CosmosDB upgrade causes "Distict query requires a matching order by in order to return a continuation token" error

Tags: .net, vb.net, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

We are running a production app on Azure CosmosDB for at least a year and this morning on Febuary 6th 2019 arround 10 AM (Eastern time -5) our application started to return HTTP 500 errors for no reason.

After exhaustive investigation, we found out that the error is coming from the Azure CosmosDB SQL .NET API ver 2.2.2 Library returning the following error :

> Distict query requires a matching order by in order to return a
>   continuation token

*No i did not do a typo with the word "Distict" instead of "Distinct"; Microsoft did !  It is a cut and paste from the error.*

Here is our query :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.city_sm 
 FROM c  
 WHERE c.partition = 'aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee'
 AND c.dataview_id = 'aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee'   
 AND c.dataview_ver = 260   
 AND c.type = 'city_sm'  
 AND c.culture = 'fr'
```

On the .NET side we are using the following Client.FeedOptions and code :

```
Client.FeedOptions.MaxItemCount = 100

' Query the list of items
oQuery = BuildSearchSqlQuerySpec(Of ItemType)(Account, DataView, SearchParams)
oDDBResult = DDClient.CreateDocumentQuery(Of ItemType)(
Client.UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(Core.Config.PublishDB.Database, Core.Config.PublishDB.Collection), 
                    oQuery, 
                    oOptions).AsDocumentQuery()

oResponse = oDDBResult.ExecuteNextAsync(Of ItemType).Result
```

And after the query we try to get the Continuation Token like this :

```
If (oDDBResult.HasMoreResults) Then
    oResult.next_token = oResponse.ResponseContinuation
End If
```

This is when the error occure and it seams to be returned by the SQL Library, not the AZURE server since i do not have any error on Azure.

I tried adding ORDER BY c.city_sm to my query to fix the issue.  I had no more errors but the query was returning no records probably because i did not have a range index on the c.city_sm field.   So to be quick and fix the production app down issue, i simply removed the DISTINCT keyword and it worked.

How can they change something on the AZURE production server that breaks existing code ?  I don't know how to reach out Microsoft and i am wonderring if anybody else experienced issues on that Febuary 6th date ?

Comment: So... just to clarify: the error is related to SDK v2.2.2, which was (according to Nuget) just released (I believe a day ago). So, my guess is that it's related to the SDK, not the service itself (FYI there's no notion of a "production server"). Have you tried reverting your code to v2.2.1 of the SDK? Since everything worked prior to yesterday, my guess is that something might have changed in the latest SDK build, and that your issues would be resolved if you went back to the prior SDK version.

Comment: Also: if that is indeed the root cause, seems like it's worth testing with new SDKs before releasing code into production.

Comment: One more thing: I'd suggest opening an issue against the [github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2) related to the error you ran into (including the error message error as well).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  No, the installed app on the server was using version 2.2.1 for at least 6 month and have not made any update.   The application stopped working by itself.  In our effort to resolve the issue, we upgraded to 2.2.2 but the problem kept happening.   So what i am saying is something have changed on the server side but the error is raised by the library because the exception happen only when we try to get back the continuation token, not when we execute the query.

Comment: At this point, I'd suggest reaching out directly to the Cosmos DB team. If something changed regarding the service itself, this really isn't the forum to discuss / speculate (since Stack Overflow isn't intended to be a product-specific support site). They have support via twitter, msdn forums, service tickets...

Comment: I did some more investigation with Fiddler trying to find out what is happening under the hood between the .NET Client and the CosmosDB server and i found out that my query is actually working fine and the server is even returning a continuation token but, proabably because of a server behavior change, it stopped working and now the library is throwing an exception by itself when accessign the property.

To see the details of my issue on GitHub [Click here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/674)

Comment: We're running into the same problem. @PatriceBechard did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @KaiG, unfortunatly not !  If you take a look at our GitHub thread, somebody else ran into the same issue but no response from the CosmosDB team.  On our side we had to remove the "DISTINCT" keyword and remove the duplicates in our application to resolve this.   On top of that we ran into another issue with ORDER BY where if you order by a field that is not present in all records, thoses records are not returned !  I really think ORDER BY is not a solid feature of CosmosDB.